# python: multiple inheritance design

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

below is a description of an oop design scenario in python:

1. a library developer made 2 classes `A` and `B` for others to use:

   ```
   class A:
       def foo(self):
           print('A')

   class B(A):
       def foo(self):
           super().foo()
           print('B')
   ```

   they are very intuitive and work correctly in his test:

   ```
   A().foo()   #   A
   B().foo()   #   AB
   ```
2. an application developer takes this library, and wants to use it in his own
   project; so he makes 2 new classes `C` and `D`;

   he decided `C` is a subclass of `A`, but the specific function `foo` in `C`
   does not need to call its super class implementation:

   ```
   class C(A):
       def foo(self):
           print('C')
   ```

   his test of `C`:

   ```
   C().foo()   #   C
   ```

   finally, `D` is a minimal multiple inheritance from both `B` and `C`;

   ```
   class D(B, C): pass
   ```

   note. if you want to make it explicit what `D.foo()` does here, you can use either `super().foo()` or `B.foo(self)`, but the result is the same:

   ```
   class D(B, C):
       def foo(self):
           super().foo()   # semantic: call `foo` in *that* super class
           #B.foo(self)     # semantic: call `foo` in `B`
   ```

till now, each step is simple and logical, right? but when he tests `D`:

```
D().foo()   #   CB
```

given `D` extends in order of `B` then `C`, the output `CB` looks illogical; one
would typically expect `D().foo()` to call at least one of `B().foo()` and `C().foo()`, but
this result is neither `AB` nor `C` nor `ABC`;

my question is not about the machinery of class inheritance or mro in python; it
is: why do we get an illogical result following logical design choices in each
step? specifically, when we utilize `super()` in multiple inheritance, do we really need to
check the *whole* class hierarchy to make sure *every* class involved (which can be defined in library, library of library, ...) is working
*cooperatively*?

i hope the answer can focus on the application developer perspective; what principles he needs to follow so that he knows the library classes work correctly in his own extended class hierarchy?

---

to give a more realistic example, suppose we are writing a game of wildlife; we need to implement, for each kind of animal, what they say when they are being kicked:

```
class Animal:
    def kick(self):
        return 'are you ok? '

class RunnableAnimal(Animal):
    def kick(self):
        return super().kick() + \
                'i am running away. '

class FuriousAnimal(Animal):
    def kick(self):
        return 'i am attacking you! '

class Tiger(RunnableAnimal, FuriousAnimal):
    def kick(self):
        return super().kick()

print(Tiger().kick())
```

output:

```
i am attacking you! i am running away.
```

this is obviously illogical: the tiger cannot perform two different actions at the same time;

Comment: The result is as expected. When you define `D` as inheriting from `B, C`, `D` ends up with a mro of `D` -> `B` -> `C` -> `A` so when you call `D().foo()` you get the call to `super` from `B` which calls and prints `C.foo` and then prints "B" as `C.foo` returns. The illogical thing here is `C.foo` returning and not calling `super`

Comment: @IainShelvington If you call `super().foo()` in `C.foo()`, then `C().foo()` outputs `AC` not `C`.

Comment: that depends if you put the call to super before or after the print, no?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, either `CA` or `AC` but neither is the wanted `C`;

Comment: What is your desired output? You have inherited from a class that has decided that is does not need to call `super` for the `foo` method and that is the behaviour you are getting

Comment: @IainShelvington Good question. Let us make it explicit there. Let us say `D.foo()` needs to call the implementation in `B`, so you can write `super().foo()`, `super(D, self).foo()`, or `B.foo(self)`. But sadly all of them still give `CB` not `AB`.

Comment: I would say in that case that you should not have `C` as a superclass of `D`

Comment: @IainShelvington This is just classic diamond inheritance. You can find many real world examples: shoes, black shoes, leather shoes, black leather shoes. If a language can't express diamond inheritance then multiple inheritance is broken there. (It is broken in Java, for example.)